# Server side listener for rich:dataScroller (RF 4.1)

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm using an `extendedDataTable` because I need multiselect. The table can get pretty large, so I'm using a `dataScroller` for paging.

What I want to achieve is, that the selection is cleared when switching to another page. The selection is stored in the backing bean and I have a method `clearTableSelection` to clear the  selection.

Now my question is, how is it possible to call the method `clearTableSelection` when switching pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution:

```
...
<rich:extendedDataTable>
    ...
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <rich:dataScroller 
            onbegin="document.getElementById('form:hiddenButton').click()" />
    </f:facet>
</rich:extendedDataTable>
<a4j:commandButton 
    id="hiddenButton" action="#{backingBean.clearTableSelection}"
    value="HiddenButton" execute="@this" style="display: none;" />
...
```